# Arrange crosstalk graphs via bscols

Tags: r, crosstalk

I am trying to have one plotly graph and a plotly map connected via crosstalk in R.
I know how to control the width of each graph like this:

```
bscols(widths = c(6, 6),
 graph, map)
```

But I am getting the half size output. How to control the height? I want to have the graph and a map full size: from top to bottom of the screen. Currently I am getting the upper half of the screen split in two equal widths (6,6). In fact I have the same thing which is presented here in this book:

https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html#filter   - Chapter 16.2, Graph 16.9:

Graph is here:
https://plotly-r.com/interactives/plotly-leaflet-filter.html

Code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(quakes)

eqs <- highlight_key(quakes)

stations <- filter_slider("station", "Number of Stations", eqs, ~stations)

p <- plot_ly(eqs, x = ~depth, y = ~mag) %>% add_markers(alpha = 0.5) %>% highlight("plotly_selected")

map <- leaflet(eqs) %>%  addTiles() %>% addCircles()

bscols(
widths = c(6, 6, 3), 
 p, map, stations)
```

Comment: Have you had any luck in figuring this out?

Comment: unfortunately no, sorry for late answer

Answer (score 1):

Width and height of charts can be passed as arguments in the original plotly() and leaflet() calls, before passing both objects to bscols() like so:

library(leaflet)
library(quakes)

eqs <- highlight_key(quakes)

stations <- filter_slider("station", "Number of Stations", eqs, ~stations)

p <- plot_ly(eqs, x = ~depth, y = ~mag, width = "100%", height = 800) %>% add_markers(alpha = 0.5) %>% highlight("plotly_selected")

map <- leaflet(eqs, width = "100%", height = 800) %>%  addTiles() %>% addCircles()

bscols(
widths = c(6, 6, 3),
p, map, stations)